# Vim Perl autocomplete displaying a given modules functions

Tags: perl, vim, autocomplete, function

Is it possible to have Vim autocomplete show which functions are available to a given module?
So if I include a module called math and then go:
math::
and at that i could get a list of the functions available through that module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin [AutoComplPop](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879) does this, if you also have [Perl omnicompletion](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2852) set up.